# Platform Event not listed when creating trigger from Developer Console

Tags: apex, trigger, developer-console, platform-event

My app has a platform event (Log_Event__e). I'm trying to make a trigger on the event from the Developer Console (using a Scratch org on API v41 with a managed package namespace).

When I attempt to create the trigger, Log_Event__e is not listed in the available choices in the "New Apex Trigger" dialog box.

[image]

Do platform event triggers need to be created in another manner? If so, how can they be created?

Comment: You had the console opened when creating the event from the UI? If so, then refresh your console (F5 or Ctrl+F5) and try again. The console will refresh the metadata and the object will show up on the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create the trigger from the platform event object page just like for  any other objects.